# What options are there for reading passive RFID tags up to 1 meter with an app?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I have heard that you can use NFC but supposedly that only works up to 4cm - I need 1 meter.

Do I need an RFID reader board, an RFID antennae and an Arduino board to glue the reader board and the antennae together?

What's the easiest approach?

Answer (score 0):

First, NFC can only read High Frequency RFID (HF-RFID). That's only a specific subset so if you do go that route, be sure it's HF.

Now, your best option is to just buy an RFID reader. You can find a lot of them with a simple search. atlasrfidstore is one that comes up pretty often. I personally use SerialIO bluetooth HID readers because I handle RFID, NFC, HID cards, and SmartCards. Plus, with the bluetooth you can use it with any bluetooth device. However, HID readers cost about $400. You can probably find some good RFID mobile sleds for a lot cheaper. I know newegg has some USB ones for about $100.

Yes, you can make your own, and possibly for a decent price using an online guide, but I find it best to buy something if you are looking for a marketable prototype application or building a solution for an enterprise.